# Обмен данными между серверами

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Допустим, есть у меня 2 сервера, независимых друг от друга со своими БД.
Допустим, на 1 сервере хранится список заказов интернет-магазина.

Есть 2 сервер, на котором есть, скажем, внутренний сайт.

Задача:
Нужно со 2 сервера получить данные о заказах с 1 сервера, сделать какие-либо пометки/изменения там и вернуть результат обратно на 1 сервер. При этом прямого подключения к БД другого сервера нет.

Мне в голову пришли вариант только с SOAP, XML-RPC, сокеты.
Есть ли еще какие-либо варианты обмена данными между серверами? В приоритете, конечно, с использованием PHP, но не обязательно.
Вроде в Интернете натыкался на разное, да как-то из-за ненадобности всё "мимо ушей пропускал".

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да в целом обмен через XML вполне сгодится, а еще проще даже через JSON. С1 выплевывает все необходимые данные при пост запросе с сервера два, С2 обрабатывает данные, как надо, и закидывает обратно в JSON в пост запросе на С1. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

А не лучше ли с сервера1 подключаться к базе сервера2, работать там, делать что надо? Зачем городить трёхэтажные дома, с дверью подъезда на уровне чердака?

Comment: > прямого подключения к БД другого сервера нет